# How to get record from a specified date range

Tags: python, sql, firebird

I'm working with software which uses Firebird for data storage. I use Python and fdb library for working with Firebird. I try to get all records from specified range of dates, but fdb raises different exceptions for all my attempts.

Date has data type - TIMESTAMP in db

Attempt 1:

```py
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN "2023-07-14" AND "2023-05-08"'
```

> Exception: `('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -206\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -206\n- Column unknown\n- 2023-07-16\n- At line 1, column 73', -206, 335544569)`

Attempt 2:

```py
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN "2023-07-14 09:00" AND "2023-05-08 17:00"'
```

Exception in this attempt equals exception in attempt 1

Attempt 3:

```py
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN %s AND %s"' % (datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 16, 9), datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 8, 17))
```

> Exception: `('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 2, column 48\n- 09', -104, 335544569)`

I searched Google and didn't find information about this problem. I also tried converting types using `CAST()`, but this didn't help.

How I understand it, the problem is with the date type.

Because this request works:

```py
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

And this request doesn't work:

```py
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = "2023-07-16 22:00:00.000"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in SQL (both in Firebird and the ISO/IEC 9075-2 standard), things enclosed in double quotes are [identifiers](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-structure-identifiers.html) (e.g. column names), not values. That is why this produce a *"Column unknown"* error.

Using double quotes to enclose string [literals](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-commons.html#fblangref40-commons-constants) is only possible in dialect 1 databases, and that has been deprecated since 2000 and shouldn't be used anymore, and judging by the error you're using dialect 3. You need to enclose string literals in single quotes.

In other words, you need to use `BETWEEN '2023-07-14' AND '2023-05-08'` (or better yet, `BETWEEN date '2023-07-14' AND date '2023-05-08'` or `BETWEEN timestamp '2023-07-14' AND timestamp '2023-05-08'`, to make the type explicit

Also, never, ever use solutions like your third attempt. String interpolation like that is essentially a form of SQL injection, and if your values come from an unsanitized source (e.g. user input), you'd be creating a security hole in your application. The actual reason for the error you get is that your value is not enclosed in single quotes. If you want to use parameterized queries, use actual parameters (`?`) and execute them by passing the values as a tuple as the second argument of `execute`.

As an aside, FDB is no longer maintained and has been replaced by [firebird-driver](https://pypi.org/project/firebird-driver/), you may want to consider upgrading to that driver.